# First time class programming in c++ and my programm doesn't work

Tags: c++

I am a hobby programmer and have now worked with classes for the first time in the course of a book. When I entered my "test" code in Microsoft Visual Studio, I received this feedback:

*1>MSVCRT.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2001: not resolved external symbol "_WinMain@16".*

I then tried to modify my code, but I didn't understand Microsoft's description of LNK2001. So I simply ask here why the following code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    myClass obj;

    cout << obj.output(5);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

as source repos and

```
#pragma once

class myClass
{


    public:

        int output(int exp)
        {

            name = exp;

            return name;

        }

    private:

        int name;

    protected:

};
```

as header file. The book explanaition (the book is named: "the c++ programmer") was also not understandable for me. So I would be very happy about help, thanks.

Comment: The code is OK but you have created the wrong kind of project in Visual Studio. Start again, this time make sure you create a *Console Project* or *Console App*.

Comment: Thereby, you don't need to re-write your code. Just add your already existing source file to the new created project. FYI: [Create a C++ console app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/get-started/tutorial-console-cpp?view=vs-2019)